# Disjoint union of random graphs again a random graph?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

Let $G_{n,p}, n\in \mathbb{N}, p\in(0,1)$ be the binomial random graph, i.e. a graph on $n$ vertices where an edge is in $G_{n,p}$ with probability $p$. Also, let $q\in (0,1)$.

Can one regard $G_{n,q}$ as a disjoint union of many $G_{n,p}$?

Comment: I think that you can whenever $p = kq$, where $k$ is a nonnegative integer.

Comment: Can you explain the idea of this question?

Comment: I read this idea in the context mentioned by Andrew Uzzell, which is proofs regarding a monotonically increasing property, though couldn't quite grasp it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Monotone properties of graphs correspond to the situation opposite to the one you describe in your question (not a disjoint union, whatever that means, but an inclusion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one is willing to drop the disjointness requirement, then the answer is yes, for appropriate values of $q$.  For example, if $q = 2p - p^2$, then $G_{n,q}$ will have the distribution of the union of two random graphs with distribution $G_{n,p}$.  (Since each edge $e$ has probability $p$ of being in either of the two graphs with distribution $G_{n,p}$, the probability that $e$ is an at least one of them is $2p - p^2$.)

In general, if $G_1$ has the distribution of $G_{n,p_1}$, $G_2$ has the distribution of $G_{n,p_2}$, and $q = p_1 + p_2 - p_1 p_2$, then a random graph with distribution $G_{n,q}$ will have the distribution of the union of $G_1$ and $G_2$.

The fact that it is possible to couple $G_{n,p}$ and $G_{n,q}$ in this way is often useful.  For example, this type of argument can be used to show that if $\mathcal{P}$ is an increasing property of graphs, then the probability that a random graph with distribution $G_{n,p}$ is in $\mathcal{P}$ is increasing in $p$.

Comment: The answer should be trivially "no" for disjoint unions though, right?

Comment: @LordSoth Yes, because if you specify "disjoint union", then by definition you're giving up the independence of different edges, so the second graph can't have the distribution of $G_{n,p}$.

Comment: Don't you need to have the disjointness for your example? Say $A,B$ are graphs with distribution $G_{n,p}$, then you use that for some edge $e$, $\mathbb{P}(e\in A\cap B) = \mathbb{P}(e\in A) \mathbb{P}(e\in B)=p^2$, i.e. $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Comment: @madison54 What exactly do you mean by disjointness here? I (and it seems like most here) think that you are referring to edge-disjoint, for which the answer to the question is no. Andrew Uzzell does use the equation $P(e \in A\cap B)=P(e \in A)P(e \in B)$, in finding $P(e \in A \cup B)=P(e \in A)+P(e \in B)-P(e \in A \cap B) = 2p - p^2$; however, I don't see what this has to do with "disjointness."

Answer (score 1):

Note: I read your question as having chosen a single $p$ and $q$ ($p < q$) in advance. If this is not what you intended, then my answer may not be relevant.

If there is a large difference between $p$ and $q$, then the random graph $G_{n,q}$ possesses properties that disjoint unions of $G_{n,p}$ do not.

As an example, suppose $nq$ tends to a constant greater than $1$ while $np$ is less than $1$. The random graph $G_{n,q}$ almost surely has a [giant connected component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_component). Each component of $G_{n,p}$, however, is almost surely of at most logarithmic size, so their disjoint union cannot possibly have a giant component.

(See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model#Properties_of_G.28n.2C_p.29) for more on the evolution of random graphs.)